# why ajax callback is setting undefined in my local variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a bug in my site, because of this strange behavior.
The second function alerts "undefined" instead of "one".

```
function test() {
    var myParam = "one"
    if (false) {
        var myParam = "two";
    }
    alert(myParam);
}
test(); // alert "one"


function testAjax() {
    var myParam = "one";
    $.ajax({
        url:    "http://url-to-get-error",
        error:  function(){
            if (false) {
                var myParam = "two";
            }
            alert(myParam);
        }
    });
}
testAjax(); // alert "undefined"
```

And if I comment block bellow, alerts "one" correctly. 
Someone knows why?

```
if (false) {
var myParam = "two";
}
```

See in http://jsfiddle.net/EaW8D/2/.

---

**UPDATE**

Guys, I know how to to solve the problem, thanks a lot!

But the question is **WHY js is setting undefined** in a block
that NEVER run (`if (false)`).

Comment: Be specific about your question inital post asks for ..**The second function alerts "undefined" instead of "one".** ..late in your update you ask for ** WHY ** ?this causes confusion on the anwsers which we provide.

Comment: Sorry, but in the first post i wrote **And if I comment block bellow, alerts "one" correctly. Someone knows why?**....so, I think that I asked why.

Comment: Fine have just read it at first I went through with your provided JSFiddle..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Someone knows why?

You are re-declaring `myParam` inside the error handler, **shadowing** the variable with the same name in the outer scope. Variable declarations are **"hoisted"** to the top of the function, so your code is effectively the same as:

```
error:  function(){
    var myParam;  // <- declaration
    if (false) {
        myParam = "two"; // <-  initialization
    }
    alert(myParam);
}
```

and since the `if` block is never executed, `myParam` will be `undefined` (the default value for uninitialized variables).

Here is a simple example to proof this behaviour. If the variable was not hoisted, `foo` would become a global variable (assuming non-strict mode) and a property of `window`, but it does not:

```
(function() {
    if(false) {
        var foo = 'bar';
    }
    foo = 'baz';
    console.log(window.foo); // yields `undefined`
}());
```

---

To solve this problem, simply remove `var`, so that `myParam` refers to the variable declared in the outer scope, `testAjax`:

```
error:  function(){
    if (false) {
        myParam = "two";
    }
    alert(myParam);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're creating `myParam` as a `new` `var` again

```
function testAjax() {
    var myParam = "one";
    $.ajax({
        url:    "http://url-to-get-error",
        error:  function(){
            if (false) {
                myParam = "two";
            }
            alert(myParam);
        }
    }); 
}
testAjax(); // alert "undefined"​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mKdhx/

Comment: Why is the previous definition unset even when the execution never reaches the `var myParam = "two";` line?

Answer (score 2):

All variable declarations of the form `var myParam` are [*hoisted*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the function scope.  Even if they are in inaccessible blocks or at the end of the function, a function with a `var` declaration in it *anywhere* will treat all instance of that variable name as local.

Consider this handler:

```
    error:  function(){
        alert(myParam);
        var myParam;
    }
```

It will also cause a `undefined` alert, because the `var myParam` at the bottom means, "*Treat all instance of `myParam` that come both before and after this declaration as local variables in this function.*"  The same hoisting that applies in this case applies in your inaccessible-logic-block case.

Answer (score -1):

in second situation your myParam=one and myParam=two are in different blocks - and moreover callback of ajax error is not "under" testAjax in terms of variable visibility - it's asynchroneus. You would need myParam in global scope

Comment: I didn't downvote, but they're in two different *functions* -- JS has function scope, not block scope.  Also, it doesn't actually have to be in *global* scope, it could exist in a non-global shared scope, like a function that wraps all the code.

Comment: agreed about global scope. about block scope - yes I meant function scope - just didn't say correctly